# How to validate enum values against DB values in spring boot on application startup

Tags: java, database, enums, spring-boot

I have created tables for enums in DB and applied referential integrity with main tables. But I need to validate the enum values against the DB values on application start up in spring boot.

Answer (score 0):

Spring provides a `Lifecycle` interface that you can implement, and the container will notify you once it has started. You can then query your db to perform whatever checks you need. From the documentation:

> Any Spring-managed object may implement that interface. Then, when the ApplicationContext itself starts and stops, it will cascade those calls to all Lifecycle implementations defined within that context. It does this by delegating to a LifecycleProcessor:

Answer (score 0):

For spring boot in particular, I find the easiest solution to be the [SpringApplicationRunListener](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/1.1.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplicationRunListener.html)

If the class is not automatically added by @ComponentScan, you will have to implement your Listener and register it in the spring.factories file.

```
 org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListener=xxx.MyListener
```

It defines very clear hooks for the spring boot lifecycle.  Attention: although it is only an interface, the implementing class must provide a special constructor:

```
public MyListener(SpringApplication application, String[] args) {}
```